# Avoid dupplicating files and services if there are more than one bundles in the application

Tags: php, symfony

I just want to know what is the best practise/way of doing this. I'm going to explain with an example to make it easier to understand.

**Note:** So far example below work fine if I have only one bundle in my application. Question is at the bottom of the post.

Thanks in advance

**SingleBundle/Resources/config/services.yml**

```
services:
    form_errors:
        class:  Hello\SingleBundle\Services\FormErrors
```

**FormErrors.php**

```
namespace Hello\SingleBundle\Services;

use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

class FormErrors
{
    public function getErrors(FormInterface $form)
    {
        .......
        .......
        return $errors;
    }
}
```

**QUESTION:**
How do I avoid duplicating these two files if I have more than one bundles in my application? Where do I define service and the service class whcih will be accesible from all the bundles?

Comment: The general approach is to prepend your service with the bundle alias so your `form_errors` would be `hello_single.form_errors`. This should stop any conflicts.

Comment: These two files are common to all the bundles. Under which bundle will I keep those files though? If I have 10 bundles, do I have to have 10 coppies of them in all 10 bundles? If not, where can I keep common stuff to all the bundles and access them?

Comment: Put the class in its own bundle, and then have all the other bundles reference it there. You can set the new bundle as a dependency of the other bundles, to make sure that it's always available.

Comment: @Erik - I can put the class in one bundle which is fine but I cannot do the rest of your suggestion because of my limited knowledge:) Do you mind showing me an example please, or an answer? Thanks

Comment: Ah, I get you. You were asking more in the terms of lack of duplication rather than conflicts. Like @Erik said, make a common bundle that all of the bundles can then reference. If you are going to upload them to any sort of VCS and then install them using composer then you would put this common bundle in your set of `requires` meaning that it would automatically include it when downloading any of the other bundles.

Comment: OK, I created a `Common` bundle and want to access its Service from `Hello` bundle. I moved files into `Common` bundle as well. `Hello` bundle has nothing in it as service entry and the service class. How do I do `$this->get('form_errors')->getErrors($form);` in `Hello` bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define your service in the bundle which implements logic of this service. If you have bundle SingleBundle the best way to call the service is to use special prefix (single_bundle.form_errors in your case).
If you have two or more bundles it's not necessary to duplicate service definition and service class declaration because all services defined in the namespace of one bundle (which is properly loaded to the project) are accessible in the namespace of the other bundle (which is properly loaded to the project as well).

So, I think before create a service you just need to think where it should be defined. And take care about service name if you have any doubts about possible duplicates.

Comment: OK I did it. Thanks. Since this is the only answer, I'll accepts it. +1. I'll upvote Erik and Qoop above because they gave correct answer too.

Comment: Never mind. It's not about points. I just tried to share my experience.